# Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only(on one environment)

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

In an application of ours,during an operation I am getting this error "Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only"

In the logs i can see this-

> 2024-01-05 09:22:57,933 42727339 INFO  o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback - Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
>
> 2024-01-05 09:22:57,934 42727340 [oam-scheduled-task-pool-2] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step stepBuilder:3ce73466-e19f-42e1-b346-8cff85c5337e in job TaskStep-stepBuilder:3ce73466-e19f-42e1-b346-8cff85c5337e
> org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Also in the logs for an insert operation in one of the classes its giving this error-

> error could not execute batch; SQL [insert into table1(created_by, created_date, cc_key,  updated_by, updated_date, value_short, is_short, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1, ?)]

The strange thing is that everything is working fine in the local as well as one other higher environment but in this specific environment it is failing.
I crosschecked all the DDl changes,application.yml in this environment and everything is fine.

Java version-17
Spring boot version- 3.0.1
Database- Oracle 19c

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

So the transaction is marked for rollback because an sql exception is raised, so that's not the problem here.

The problem might be the fact that on that table you have some constraints that upon insertion, get activated.

You only see this in production, maybe because you have a lot more data there than in the other environment.

What i suggest is to check what values you're trying to write to the db, check the constraint and then you might figure out why the writing to the db fails.